# How to generate apks with different ABIs for instrumentation tests?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-instrumentation

I can get multiple apks for different ABIs of my app when I add this to build.gradle:

```
android {
    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            universalApk true
        }
    }
}
```

as can be seen here:

```
./build/outputs/apk/debug/MyApp-arm64-v8a-debug.apk
./build/outputs/apk/debug/MyApp-armeabi-v7a-debug.apk
./build/outputs/apk/debug/MyApp-universal-debug.apk
./build/outputs/apk/debug/MyApp-x86-debug.apk
./build/outputs/apk/debug/MyApp-x86_64-debug.apk
```

but it doesn't work for instrumentation tests apk:

```
./build/intermediates/apk/androidTest/debug/MyApp-debug-androidTest.apk
```

How to do it also for instrumentation tests?

Comment: do your tests contain any abi-specific code? or .so files?

Comment: @Lino no, just java and kotlin tests but when I try to install MyApp-debug-androidTest.apk I'm getting INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS, so it looks like I need to have it for correct architecture but as I wrote I'm only able to get that for app whereas instrumentation seems to be build only for single arch